# Is everything a vector in R?

Tags: r, vector

I have dabbled with Pandas in Python doing some manipulations and regressions on data I collected and answering SO questions, and thought learning the inspiration of it might help my understanding.

I'm using the learn-R tutorial and after [vector](https://www.learn-r.org/r-tutorial/vector.php) and some digging on SO and the web, I come to this:

```r
# So assigning a value to v will create an atomic vector
# of length one with a type
v <- 1
is.vector(v)  # TRUE
class(v)  # 'numeric'
# But literals are also vectors? These all return TRUE
is.vector(1)
is.vector("string literal")
is.vector(TRUE)
is.vector("c")

# and lists are vectors too
l <- list(1, 2, 3)
is.vector(l)  # TRUE
```

So is everything a vector in R?

Comment: Basic data structures of R include: vectors, lists , data.frame and matrix

Comment: (@tushaR, I'd generalize "matrix": it only has 2 dimensions, while `"array"` can have an arbitrary number of dimensions but is otherwise perfectly compatible. `identical(matrix(1:3, nrow=1), array(1:3, dim=c(1,3)))` is true.)

Comment: R has no scalar data type. All data types are atomic or generic vectors (lists). I recommend reading the language definition: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#List-objects

Comment: Everything in R is an object. `is.vector(df)` return `FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks. I was starting to think something similar to Lisp's "everything is a list" was going on. But `is.vector(is.vector)` is `FALSE` too. The language definition is a good read :)

Comment: The short answer to your question is no, not everything is a vector. For example `is.vector(a~b)`; `is.vector(base::sum)`; `is.vector(function(x) x+ 1)`; and`is.vector(new.env())` and `is.vector(factor("a"))`. But most data is "vector-like"

Comment: Functions are not vectors. If they were, objects of type closure might be subsettable. ;)

Comment: R's original implementation was based on a Scheme interpreter, so any resemblance to Lisp is not a coincidence.

Comment: Not all objects are vectors but data objects such as scalars (which are not distinct objects but are 1 element vectors), atomic vectors, lists, arrays, matrices (which are 2d arrays) and data.frame objects are all vectors.  A matrix is a vector with a dim attribute and a data.frame is a list of columns (where each column in a vector of the same length) and so is also a vector because a list is.  If m <- diag(3) is a 3x3 diagonal matrix one can refer to m[3,3] to get its last element but one can also treat it as a vector and refer to m[9].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, some things are not vectors in R, but most ways you would want to store data are vectors.  Confusing the issue is that `is.vector()` has a weird definition:  it doesn't allow attributes.  For example,

```r
x <- 1:3
is.vector(x)
#> [1] TRUE
attr(x, "foo") <- "bar"
x
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> attr(,"foo")
#> [1] "bar"
is.vector(x)
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

I would say that `x` is still a vector even with the attribute, but the `is.vector()` function thinks things with attributes aren't vectors.  For a ridiculous example:  according to `is.vector()`, factors aren't vectors, but you can treat them as if they are:

```r
x <- factor(letters[1:4])
is.vector(x)
#> [1] FALSE
x
#> [1] a b c d
#> Levels: a b c d
x[2:3]
#> [1] b c
#> Levels: a b c d
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

So if we define vectors to be objects that can be indexed using `[]` or `[[]]`, then most data types (types built from logical, integer, numeric, complex, character and raw, as well as lists) are vectors.  There are no scalars of those types in R.

On the other hand, if you define vectors to be objects for which `is.vector()` returns `TRUE`, there are lots of data types that aren't vectors: factors, matrices, arrays, time series, data.frames, etc.  So don't do that.  :-)

Your examples using literals work that way because R doesn't treat literal values in any special way.  They are just expressions that give objects.

Some things really aren't vectors:  the `NULL` object, language objects like names (e.g. `as.name("x")`), environments, functions, etc.